# How to fix it: LLVM llc error: Assertion `Val && "isa<> used on a null pointer"' failed

Tags: c++, iterator, llvm

I am working on a project base on LLVM 7.0.0, I transfer the llvm version form 3.5 to 7.0.0, I have build the project and is ok, but when I  running llc on a .bc file, here is the bug confused me, I have find everything on the Internet and no solution, here is the stack dump message:

llc: llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:106: static bool llvm::isa_impl_cl<To, const From*>::doit(const From*) [with To = llvm::StructType; From = llvm::CompositeType]: Assertion `Val && "isa<> used on a null pointer"' failed.

---

Bug in code here:

```
int64_t DataLayout::getIndexedOffsetInType(Type *ElemTy,
                                           ArrayRef<Value *> Indices) const {
  int64_t Result = 0;

  generic_gep_type_iterator<Value* const*>
    GTI = gep_type_begin(ElemTy, Indices),
    GTE = gep_type_end(ElemTy, Indices);
  for (; GTI != GTE; ++GTI) {   // stack dump here when ++GTI
    Value *Idx = GTI.getOperand();
    if (StructType *STy = GTI.getStructTypeOrNull()) {
      assert(Idx->getType()->isIntegerTy(32) && "Illegal struct idx");
      unsigned FieldNo = cast<ConstantInt>(Idx)->getZExtValue();

      // Get structure layout information...
      const StructLayout *Layout = getStructLayout(STy);

      // Add in the offset, as calculated by the structure layout info...
      Result += Layout->getElementOffset(FieldNo);
    } else {
      // Get the array index and the size of each array element.
      if (int64_t arrayIdx = cast<ConstantInt>(Idx)->getSExtValue())
        Result += arrayIdx * getTypeAllocSize(GTI.getIndexedType());
    }
  }

  return Result;
}
```

```
    generic_gep_type_iterator& operator++() {   // Preincrement
      Type *Ty = getIndexedType();   // program is stack dump here.
      if (auto *STy = dyn_cast<SequentialType>(Ty)) {
        CurTy = STy->getElementType();
        NumElements = STy->getNumElements();
      } else
        CurTy = dyn_cast<StructType>(Ty);
      ++OpIt;
      return *this;
    }
```

```
template <class X, class Y>
LLVM_NODISCARD inline typename cast_retty<X, Y *>::ret_type dyn_cast(Y *Val) {
  return isa<X>(Val) ? cast<X>(Val) : nullptr; //stack dump here
}
```

Then when I debug the program, I find this message:

llvm/include/llvm/IR/GetElementPtrTypeIterator.h:

```
   // FIXME: Make this the iterator's operator*() after the 4.0 release.
   // operator*() had a different meaning in earlier releases, so we're
   // temporarily not giving this iterator an operator*() to avoid a subtle
   // semantics break.
   Type *getIndexedType() const {
     if (auto *T = CurTy.dyn_cast<Type *>())
       return T;
     return CurTy.get<StructType *>()->getTypeAtIndex(getOperand());
   }
  
   Value *getOperand() const { return const_cast<Value *>(&**OpIt); }
  
   generic_gep_type_iterator &operator++() { // Preincrement
     Type *Ty = getIndexedType();
     if (auto *ATy = dyn_cast<ArrayType>(Ty))
       CurTy = ATy->getElementType();
     else if (auto *VTy = dyn_cast<VectorType>(Ty))
       CurTy = VTy->getElementType();
     else
       CurTy = dyn_cast<StructType>(Ty);
     ++OpIt;
     return *this;
   }
  
   generic_gep_type_iterator operator++(int) { // Postincrement
     generic_gep_type_iterator tmp = *this;
     ++*this;
     return tmp;
   }
```

That "// FIXME: Make this the iterator's operator*() after the 4.0 release.", I am confused about what is that message want let me do, there is anything I need to add or fix at that position, so that helpful to fix the Stack dump.

Any suggestions will be be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you running `llc` on a `.ll` or `.bc` file? Or do you have your own code using LLVM as a library? The assertion is on `isa<SomeTypeHere>(some_ptr_here)` because it is nullptr yet none of the code you posted shows the failing isa<>() call.

Comment: reply to Nick Lewycky
thanks, yes, I use llc on a .bc file, failing isa<>(): 
template <class X, class Y>
LLVM_NODISCARD inline typename cast_retty<X, Y *>::ret_type dyn_cast(Y *Val) {
  return isa<X>(Val) ? cast<X>(Val) : nullptr;
}
called by dyn_cast here:
Type *CompositeType::getTypeAtIndex(const Value *V) const {
  if (auto *STy = dyn_cast<StructType>(this)) {
    unsigned Idx =
      (unsigned)cast<Constant>(V)->getUniqueInteger().getZExtValue();
    assert(indexValid(Idx) && "Invalid structure index!");
    return STy->getElementType(Idx);
  }
...

Answer (score 0):

You are having:

```cpp
      if (auto *STy = dyn_cast<SequentialType>(Ty)) {
        CurTy = STy->getElementType();
        NumElements = STy->getNumElements();
      } else
        CurTy = dyn_cast<StructType>(Ty);
```

so, if `dyn_cast` fails, then `CurTy` might be `nullptr` and on next `getIndexedType()` you'll obtain the assertion. Likely you're passing neither `SequentialType` nor `StructType` here.